# VectorDensityPlot,

Tags: plotting, variable-definitions, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to plot the following function for two different values of variable m. However, it seems the second figure never appears. Weirdly, I noticed that real numbers are being attributed to variables x and y.

```
mp[m_, r_, θ_] := {r^2 + Cos[m θ],r^2 - Sin[m θ]};
mc[m_, x_, y_]:=
  Evaluate @ TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", mp[m, r, θ], {r, θ} -> {x, y}];

{VectorDensityPlot[mc[0, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], 
 VectorDensityPlot[mc[1, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use the code in the image -- it seems the posted code has a theta missing the brackets, `\Theta` instead of `\[Theta]`, the latter being what it shown in the image of the code -- it works and give a correct plot for both.

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure your "thetas" are consistent.  After changing all the thetas, I seem to have gotten your code to work.  Please see the linked figure.

```
mp[m_, r_, θ_] := {r^2 + Cos[m θ], r^2 - Sin[m θ]};

mc[m_, x_, y_] :=
   Evaluate @ TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", mp[m, r, θ], {r, θ} -> {x, y}];

{VectorDensityPlot[mc[0, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
 VectorDensityPlot[mc[1, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}
```

[image: Vector Density Plots]

Comment: You might also consider to post the corrected code in copyable form.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I must be missing something but had to insert the code line-by-line.  Okay, only three lines!  But it could get tedious.  Probably there is a way to insert all the code at once, yes?

Comment: Copy (right-click->As Input) and paste does not work?

Comment: I tried that.  Didn't quite work.  The first two lines were copied correctly with proper indentation.  The third line was not.

Comment: Anyways, you've already got my upvote. Welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You might find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful as well as [this one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) for posting & formatting code.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here we can get beautiful pictures

```
    mp = {r^2 + Cos[m*θ], r^2 - Sin[m*θ]}; 
    mc = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
       mp, {r, θ} -> {x, y}]; 
Table[VectorDensityPlot[mc, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"m = ", m}], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  StreamPoints -> Fine], {m, 0, 9}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: This is very nice!  For m=7, for example, we see a regular heptagon and one of the heptagrams indicated in your figure.  I wonder what it would take to see the other one (or is it somehow already in the picture?). 

[Weisstein, Eric W. "Heptagram." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.] (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Heptagram.html)

Comment: This is an interesting vector field. Perhaps the author will explain what it describes.